# Unable to place ChangenotifierProvider.value in flutter to reflect the changes in the data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I am unable to place changeNotifierProvider.value for the UI to show the changes( checked and no issue with the data), If you can please guide me as to where and how to place the changeNotifierProvider.value in the below widget.Thank you.

Please let me know if u require any further information.

change.dart

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final check = Provider.of<UserProfileReadProvider>(context);

    final n = check.items;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 40, right: 10, bottom: 90.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
              child: const Text('AM'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 70),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Name : ${n.name}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: (18.0)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                Text(
                  'Address: ${n.address}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
```

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (ctx) => UserProfileReadProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (ctx) =>Page(),
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

provider.dart

```
UserProfileInformation nitems = UserProfileInformation();

Future<void> addUserinformation(
      UserProfile st, var imagecheck) async {
    
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "charset=utf-8",
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    };

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3001/userprofile/check/upload');
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      request.fields['userId'] = st.userId;
      request.fields['name'] = st.name;
      request.fields['address'] = st.address;

      var response = await request.send();

      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        st = nitems;

        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        print('invalid data ');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please specify, what information you want to update...

Comment: The most recommended way to play your ChangeNotifierProvider is at the root of the widgets that will consume the data being provided, i.e. at the top of the widget tree, wrapping the **MaterialApp** widget (if you're using Material, for example).

Comment: I want to catch the changes in the name and address field and additionally I have already added change provider in material app but wanted to know where do I place changeNotifierProvider.value in the above code to capture the change in name and address

Comment: Please add the code where you setup your provider and also where you update the values you want to be listened by this build method.

Comment: Hi I have provided the relevant details

Comment: @akhilmodi So your `ChangeNotifierProvider` has a type of `UserProfileReadProvider` but you read it like `Provider.of<UserCheckData>(context)`, that's a different type.

Comment: Hi @Peter I have made the necessary changes...I just want to know where and how should we place the ChangeNotifierProvider.value in the change.dart page so that the value being changed is captured in the name and address widget something like this child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ndata.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(

Comment: but I am having issues as the above code(change.dart) is not a listView

Comment: @akhilmodi Please check [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). Basically you need a `Consumer` or `context.watch` where you depend on the provider`s state. Then you call a setter like `context.read<MyClass>().something = value` and the setter should call `notifyListeners`.